# Can you reverse the output to count on another key?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to count the number of IDs in terms of how many times it appears in data.

Now I got

```
U6492ea665413f304b323fea3e7f76739    7
Uf873b1e4dfc9f18d92758020dc1435c6    7
Ua30d2a8da85ac1144f9cbbf390c10d3c    7
Uf169ffec7dc767b89694a26cb057a258    7
U9e9c89c308d6c2f77dad28f8ec8e7993    7
```

.
The left is ID, and the right is how many times ID appears in data.

What I wannna get is like

```
7 900
6 435
5 434
4 343
3 453
2 34
1 121 .
```

The left is the number of appearances. The right is the number of IDs.

```
uid = data['id']
col=uid.value_counts()
col
```

The information of the original data is below. 
[image: The original data]

Comment: What is the data structure? A list? A dict? A class? Post some code to demonstrate your use case please.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment!
The data structure is dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do - just reset the index to get the ids as a separate column and then group by on the counts that you previously got - then count the IDs (here they'll be called index

```py
df = col.reset_index()
df.groupby(by='count')['index'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uid = data['uid']
col=uid.value_counts()
col

num = col.value_counts()
num
```

Repeating value_counts() has resolved the issue.